# Low cost option to run Lightning node in Cloud

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network-daemon

I like to run a Lightning node and need some inputs.

Providing Internet, Electricity  24*7 to my home system/Raspberry (Umbrel setup) is super challenging in my place.

Like to know if running pruned bitcoin-core, LND in a cloud server (~$10/mo.) is a good idea?

What are the catches with this approach, apart from the obvious one of "Trusting the cloud vendor".

https://voltage.cloud/ provides a $13/mo. package (LND with Neutrino), which matches my exact requirement. But my intent is to setup and run things by myself. For the sake of learning.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is an implementation on the Google Cloud https://medium.com/coinmonks/setup-bitcoin-lightning-server-on-google-cloud-guide-95811c439b32

Comment: @sean: Thanks, I've converted your answer to a comment on the question as a seed for someone that wants to provide a full answer.